# Caps lock turning on by itself

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, capslock

I am having a strange issue with my keyboard:

Whenever I switch to a browser (Chrome or Firefox on Windows 7) from another application and start typing, the first letter I type does not appear, but instead caps lock is activated and my input appears from the second typed letter and in all caps. Hitting the caps lock key twice turns caps lock off again and I can continue typing normally. I tried switching keyboard layouts (US international, US standard, Dutch) but the problem remains. Any ideas what this is? It started yesterday.

Comment: This sounds like sticky keys, an Accessibility option. Check your Control Panel, Accessibility (Toegankelijkheidscentrum)

Comment: Doesn't sound like any kind of normal "Sticky keys"  behavior. But I agree turning Sticky Keys off is the first thing to do "just in case". Could be a browser plugin/toolbar (installed in BOTH browsers) is messing with the keyboard.

Comment: I checked the accessibility settings it but I don't see anything that would do this. Sticky keys are turned off and there is no beep when it happens.

Comment: I have some plugins on Chrome but none on Firefox. It must be something else.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by replacing the keyboard. When I connect the old keyboard to a different machine it doesn't act up though. Very strange.

Comment: Update: the same problem has started with the new keyboard.